# Remove <Super>L lock screen shortcut

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I'd like to repurpose <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, but it locks the screen and I can't figure out where to disable this. I'm using Unity.

Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> System shows the keybinding for `Lock screen` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (which works).

I've checked `dconf-editor` under `org.gnome.shell.keybindings`, and it's not there. Also searched for `screensaver`, `lock`, `<Super>l` and `Primary`, didn't find it.

I also checked `gconf-editor`, but nothing jumped out at me.

I don't have any keybindings under CompizConfig -> Commands except for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Where else are shortcuts defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just assign the keybinding to a new action, and if it's conflicting with an already existing keybinding it will just complain and ask for a confirmation:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: D'oh, that was easier than I expected. It turned out it was the Unity plugin (also in CompizConfig) that was controlling that shortcut. Confusing!